# JBoss 4.x not deploying src folder to war

Tags: java, eclipse, war

I am currently working on a web app that had previously run and deployed fine but after making a recent change JBoss will no longer deploy a complete war file.  I was hoping someone here would have some advice on how to fix it.  JBoss deploys everything in WEB-INF and META-INF fine but nothing in the class folder is getting deployed.  I am attempting to deploy as exploded.

war:

```
META-INF  
--Manifest.mf   
WEB-INF  
--classes    
----META-INF   
------xfire  
--------services.xml  
--lib  
-----lots of jars  
--ibm-web-bnd.xmi  
--ibm-web-ext.xmi 
--jboss-web.xml  
--log4j.properties  
--web.xml  
--xfire-servlet.xml
```

Edit: Sorry yes I meant class folder.

Comment: sounds like you are bundling the source code instead of the classes, or your question is just mis-written, and you mean the classes folder?

Comment: Yes my bad simply used the wrong word.

Comment: Can you modifying your question to show the directory structure of the WAR?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What were you expecting to be deployed?

Comment: I'm expecting a whole projects worth of .class files and a few xml files to be getting deployed in that class file but instead it just have xfire

Comment: Hang on... are youtelling us that the WAR structure is incomplete, or that it is complete, but Tomcat isn't deploying it?

Comment: The war is incomplete it isn't deploying class files but I figured out why one of the jars needed to compile some of the classes was corrupt so they weren't compiling.  Thank you for your help by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

[How to configure Jboss AS](http://www.ubookcase.com/book/Sams/JBoss.4.0.The.Official.Guide/0672326485/ch02lev1sec5.html)